# jQuery MFX accordion not initializing in Chrome, IE, or Safari (works fine in Firefox)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, joomla, safari, accordion

The accordion script works fine in Firefox, but apparently is the only browser it works in. Here's the link (scroll down to Q&A):

https://www.in-acuity.com/our-experts/experts_details/20-Frank%20-Koch

I'm loading the latest jQuery & UI libraries, and I have this accordion running fine on a number of other websites, with no errors. Never had a problem with this plugin. Ever.

Here is the error that's popping up in Chrome:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'height' in undefined**

I understand very generally what this means, but why it would be happening here and NOT happening in the large handful of other sites that this script is running on just fine. Been debugging for hours, and ready to throw a baby seal out a window over here.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();

$query = "[OMITTED]";
$db->setQuery( $query );
$questions = $db->loadObjectList();
$count = count($db->loadObjectList());

if($count) {

    echo '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="[OMITTED]" type="text/javascript"></script>';  

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.mfx_accordion').mfxAccordion({
                        slideSpeed: 300,
                        singleOption: true
                    });
                });
            </script>";

    echo '<div class="mfx_accordion">';

    foreach($questions as $question) {

        echo '<div class="section">
                 <h2 class="trigger settings"><span class="icon"></span>'.$question->ques.'</h2>
                 <div class="content">
                     <p>'.$question->anws.'</p>
                 </div>
              </div>';      



    }

    echo '</div>';  

}

?>
```

EDIT:

Thanks to George's assistance, was able to fix. Here is the updated, working code:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

          jQuery.noConflict(); 

          jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
              $('.mfx_accordion').mfxAccordion({
                  slideSpeed: 300,
                  singleOption: true
              });
          })(jQuery);

      </script>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kind of errors usually occur when you have jquery and mootools being used on the same page (as I can see you have got). They both use the $ symbol as a short cut for the libraries. My advice would be to look through your jquery code and replace the $ variable and see if that makes a difference

```
// Disable the $ global alias completely
jQuery.noConflict();

// For jQuery scripts
(function($){

// set a local $ variable only available in this block as an alias to jQuery
... here is your jQuery specific code ...

})(jQuery);
```

To be safe I'd also do the same sort of thing to your mootools scripts. Because that might be where the jQuery error is coming from:

```
(function($){

// set a local $ variable only available in this block as an alias 
// to Mootools document.id
... here is your Mootools specific code ...

})(document.id);
```

Comment: Thank you, George. Posted the revised, working code above. Much appreciation.